# How to get iOS simulator running iOS 3.0?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I am currently using xcode 4 and the iOS 4.3 SDK and I need to test my app in the simulator using the 3.0 OS but the earliest I can get is the iPad 3.2 OS.

How can I get the simulator to run older versions of the iPhone OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't. You'd have to be using an earlier iOS SDK version (and FYI, you can have multiple SDKs installed on your machine - just move them to a different folder when you're installing a new one).

See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14128/how-to-install-3-0-iphone-simulator-on-xcode-4) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm downloading an older SDK right now. I had no idea I could have multiple SDK's installed.

Comment: Well, there's one thing you need to consider though - unless you prepared your code from the start to be compilable on SDKs < 3.2, it probably won't compile. For instance, something as simple as the macro to check whether you're on an iPad or not (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()) won't be available on those SDKs. Of course you can rewrite your code to work around that, but just saying, there may be a bit of effort required to get it to compile. That's why I actually end up doing very little (or none at all) testing on iOS 3.1.3, even though I have it installed on my machine.

Comment: Regarding how to get the multiple SDKs on your machine - I don't know if you need to do it like this (it's probably overkill), but the way I'm doing it is moving the whole Developer directory to a different place.